# Android AlarmManager doesn´t work properly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I´m working with alarm manager on my app and I need some DefaultSharedPreferences value to be reset (set to 0) at 2:00 AM.
I have a function on my main activity which is called whenever the app is open:

```
protected void setUpAlarmManager(){ //To delete the data of each day and pass it to Records database
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent  = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 02);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pIntent); //set repeating every 24 hours
        Log.i("Set", "Alarm set");
    }
```

And then I use a BroadcastReceiver to reset the values.

```
package com.javierd.iifym;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;

import com.javierd.iifym.sqlite.RecordsDataSource;

//To delete the data of each day and pass it to Records database
public class AlarmReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {

    private RecordsDataSource dataSource;
    private Utils utils;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Time", "TIMEEEE!!!!");
        SharedPreferences macros = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //As we store data using DefaultSharedPreferences, not SharedPreferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = macros.edit();
        editor.putString("eaten_carbs", "0");
        editor.putString("eaten_proteins", "0");
        editor.putString("eaten_fats", "0");
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

The receiver works, the problem is that the AlarmManager works randomly. Although it is supposed to just at 2:00 am, maybe you enter the app at 16:00, save some values, at the next time you enter at 17:30 the values are deleted, or maybe not, it´s something random and I do not understand it.

Comment: This won’t work if the phone is turned off - alarms disappear on reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such effect is caused by using `AlarmManager.setInexectRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)` I believe.
According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but
>   it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time.

When you use this method, Android synchronizes multiple inexact repeating alarms and fires them at the same time. And taking into account that the interval is a day, the alarm might fire at 17:30.

If the alarm needs to fire exactly at 2:00 am then I'd suggest using  [AlarmManager.setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) method instead.

Please be aware that it's recommended to avoid using exact alarms if possible to reduce the drain on the battery.

Updated.

I would suggest check if the trigger time isn't in the past.

Could you please try

```
protected void setUpAlarmManager(){ //To delete the data of each day and pass it to Records database
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent  = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(calendar)) {
             calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pIntent); //set repeating every 24 hours
        Log.i("Set", "Alarm set");
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, i knew it, that is why I am ussing setInexactRepeating.
I have change it to setRepeating but it still fails.
Could the error be produced because the alarmManager is set everytime the app is opened?

Comment: @Javierd98 If the alarm is set everytime the app is opened, then yes, it might be the reason. The line `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 02);` doesn't guarantee that the result date will be in future. For example if current time is 17:30 than the result time would be 02:00, *the same day*, which is in the past. So after setting such alarm the system will try to fire it ASAP.

Comment: Ummm okay, so how should I set the alarmManager then?

Comment: @Javierd98 please, take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: You should also be aware that when you set an alarm - you are scheduling a PendingIntent for delivery. When the device is rebooted, all PendingIntent's are cleared by Android. You will need a Broadcast receiver to listen to when BOOT_COMPLETED occurs, retrieve your time of 2AM and reschedule the alarm.

Comment: Okey, so I have tried this code but it still don´t work, now it doesn´t trigger the broadcastreveiver

Comment: Scheduled alarms might be debugged, to do it one should run `adb shell dumpsys alarm` from a command prompt, or `adb shell dumpsys alarm | grep -A 5 com.package.name` to list alarms set from some particular application.